# How to disable Traefik Circuit Breaker in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I've added the Traefik Load Balancer to my Kubernetes cluster using the stable helm chart and I am having a problem with the circuit breaker.

The problem is that the circuit breaker is being triggered when it shouldn't (I think that the latency in my system greater than the default), so I would like to disable it to see if this is really what is causing our problems.

How can I don this? I didn't found any configuration in the Traefik documentation that would allow me to disable it.

Please note that we are using the Traefik as an ingress for a monolith and not for a microservice, so I have my doubts if the circuit breaker should be used at all.